# bootstrap not correct with hamburger menu

Tags: html, jquery, css, jscript

I am trying to pick up my coding after a short break and now i stumble upon the problem of the hamburger menu not collapsing and expanding. keep in mind this is work in progress i have to source file that i got from the course i am following but i dont see any difference between them besides of course the navbar-light etc (styling)
i have uploaded it to github and i hope somebody would like to help me. and if you have a solution i would like to learn from where i went wrong.
thank you all for your time

https://github.com/truezerox/pizza

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Please post enough code so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you forgot to add some script tags related to bootstrap. I updated your code. Check your github rep. (youll see the updated code in a new fork. To see that, open your repository, then click to "insights". Then you'll see "forks" at the end of the side menu).